# Using blocks and ARC is causing a "message sent to deallocated instance" error

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

I had a problem with ARC and blocks but have solved the problem. Unfortunately I don't what exactly is going on and would like to learn more about the situation I had.

Originally, I had code that did this

```
for(__block id<Foo> object in objects) {
    foo download:someParm
         success:^{
            object.state = StateNewState; 
         }
    ];
}
```

This caused an imbalance in retains. A crash occurs when an object is accessed and is said to be already deallocated. I wrote a class that implemented  and used the "copy" attribute to create a successBlock property which saved the block passed into the success parameter of the download function. I replaced the code with this with the following

```
for(id<Foo> object in objects) {
    foo download:someParm
         success:^(id<Foo> successObject){
            successObject.state = StateNewState; 
         }
    ];
}
```

No more deallocated object errors but I have yet to run instruments to check if I'm not leaking. Some how using __block is causing the object to be released too many times, and I can't figure out why. I'll continue my research as to the cause of this issue but I thought it'd be an interesting problem for the rest of you guys to think about.

I suppose it may be worth noting that the objects array was an autoreleased array that was created in the lines proceeding the code I wrote down earlier in this post. Don't think it'd matter but I thought I'd just through that out there. The code I put in this post isn't the exact code, because I'm using this for work and there's a bunch of fluff in there. But there's no other objects being created in the for loop.

When the app crashes, it runs download and then later runs the callback, I'm using ASIHttp by the way. When I attempt to download again it runs and the callback is not called, since object has been deallocated and the delegate is nil'ed. After this when object is accessed by a dictionary that contains a pointer to object we crash.

Comment: I was reading the docs and was reminded that using __block is used to not increase the retain count of an instance's ivars, by using using a __block pointer to self to reference the variables within a block.

I was wondering would it also be true that using __block would not increase the retain count for the object at id<Foo> object? Thus causing a retain imbalance when the block is released causing id<Foo> object to also be released?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Blocks Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1) says:

> Use of instance variables within the block will cause the object
> itself to be retained. If you wish to override this behavior for a
> particular object variable, you can mark it with the __block storage
> type modifier.
>
> If you are using ARC, object variables are retained and released automatically as the block is copied and later released.

Thus, if you don't use `__block`, I think you'll find your variables are being retained for you. E.g., this seems to work for me:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// add two custom objects to that array

[array addObject:[[MyObject alloc] initWithText:@"One" number:1]];
[array addObject:[[MyObject alloc] initWithText:@"Two" number:2]];
[array addObject:[[MyObject alloc] initWithText:@"Three" number:3]];

// now replace the text field in each of the three objects with the word "Done"

for (MyObject *object in array)
{
    [self blockTestInvocation:^{
        NSLog(@"%s %@", __FUNCTION__, [NSDate date]);

        object.text = @"Done";
    }];
}
```

I found that the presence or absence of `__block` didn't have a material impact when my `blockTestInvocation` invoked the passed block synchronously, but when I set it up to invoke the block asynchronously (after my array and objects would have otherwise been released), the absence of the `__block` ensured that the object was retained, thereby preventing the dreaded "message sent to deallocated instance" (and there were no leaks, either). But with `__block`, the object is not retained, and thus could be deallocated by the time the block of code tries to reference it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll be sure to be mindful of how __block prevents objects from being automatically retained.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1) Something doesn't add up about what you've described. You say you're putting these objects in an autoreleased array, which is presumably temporary storage for the purpose of running the loop. Then your block callbacks set some state on those objects, which would be pointless unless something else is also retaining them. So your problem lies in the something else--whatever created those objects should be retaining them while it needs them--presumably long enough to observe the state change. If it were, you wouldn't be getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors.

2) You don't need the `__block` qualifier in your loop. It's basically telling the compiler that your block may assign a new object to that reference, so it needs to dereference the variable. But your block doesn't do that. You're just sending a message to the object. If you don't use the `__block` qualifier, your block will take a const copy of the value--that value is a pointer to your object. Then when you do `object.state = StateNewState`, you're sending a `setState:newState` message to the object at that pointer. So this should work fine:

```
for(id<Foo> object in objects) {
    foo download:someParm
         success:^{
            object.state = StateNewState; 
         }
    ];
}
```

Comment: I agree with this observation that setting a state for an object that you don't plan on keeping around was a little weird. I assume this was just a construct of the super-simplified example, rather than a practical, real-life scenario. But I can imagine this sort of problem manifesting itself if you, for example, had already dismissed the view that initiated a download and the view was dismissed by the time the download completed.

Comment: I shouldn't have put that bit in there with the array. Ignore that.

Comment: Good insight on number 2. I was going brain dead at the end of the day but what you said is right. Don't know what I was thinking.